# Play Java - cannot connect do database postgreSQL

Tags: java, database, postgresql, playframework

I created new play-java application using activator. Now I need to connect it to a postgreSQL database. Whatever I tried, I always got this error:

```
Error in custom provider, Configuration error: Configuration error[Cannot connect to database [default]]
```

Here is my build.sbt with latest dependencies:

```
libraryDependencies += "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-901-1.jdbc4"
libraryDependencies += "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.38"
```

and here is application.conf:

```
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/table4you"
db.default.user="postgres"
db.default.password="test"
```

I  even tried this:

```
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://postgres:test@localhost:6789/table4you"
```

which also does not work. 
Afterwards I tried to check if mySQL will work, and I added mysql dependency in build.sbt and changed the driver and URL to :

```
#db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
#db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/table4you"
#db.default.user="root"
#db.default.password=""
```

and it worked! 
But I really have to make it work with postgres. Now I assume that the problem is with the database itself, and not with the application.conf file. The way I start the database is, I open pgAdmin III, and inside it I connect to my server and to table4you database (by double clicking on them).
Should I use some other way of starting postgresql database maybe? What could I do to make it work with postgresql?

EDIT: I tried this, but I get the same error again: 
I created a database on heroku, and I used the connection settings I got there (host name, username, password and database name) to use online database instead of localhost one. Shame the output is same as before :(.

Here is the stacktrace of error:

```
Unexpected exception
CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) Error in custom provider, Configuration error: Configuration error[Cannot connect to database [default]]
  while locating play.api.db.DBApiProvider
  while locating play.api.db.DBApi
    for parameter 0 at play.db.DefaultDBApi.<init>(DefaultDBApi.java:28)
  at play.db.DefaultDBApi.class(DefaultDBApi.java:28)
  while locating play.db.DefaultDBApi
  while locating play.db.DBApi
    for field at play.db.DBModule$NamedDatabaseProvider.dbApi(DBModule.java:61)
  while locating play.db.DBModule$NamedDatabaseProvider
  at com.google.inject.util.Providers$GuicifiedProviderWithDependencies.initialize(Providers.java:149)
  at play.db.DBModule.bindings(DBModule.java:40):
Binding(interface play.db.Database qualified with QualifierInstance(@play.db.NamedDatabase(value=default)) to ProviderTarget(play.db.DBModule$NamedDatabaseProvider@70606a)) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$1)
Caused by: Configuration error: Configuration error[Cannot connect to database [default]]
    at play.api.Configuration$.configError(Configuration.scala:178)
    at play.api.Configuration.reportError(Configuration.scala:829)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi$$anonfun$connect$1.apply(DefaultDBApi.scala:48)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi$$anonfun$connect$1.apply(DefaultDBApi.scala:42)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi.connect(DefaultDBApi.scala:42)
    at play.api.db.DBApiProvider.get$lzycompute(DBModule.scala:72)
    at play.api.db.DBApiProvider.get(DBModule.scala:62)
    at play.api.db.DBApiProvider.get(DBModule.scala:58)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.provision(BoundProviderFactory.java:72)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.get(BoundProviderFactory.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:104)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:145)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:56)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleFieldInjector.inject(SingleFieldInjector.java:54)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:132)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl$1.call(MembersInjectorImpl.java:93)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl$1.call(MembersInjectorImpl.java:80)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectAndNotify(MembersInjectorImpl.java:80)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.injectMembers(InjectorImpl.java:984)
    at com.google.inject.util.Providers$GuicifiedProviderWithDependencies.initialize(Providers.java:149)
    at com.google.inject.util.Providers$GuicifiedProviderWithDependencies$$FastClassByGuice$$2a7177aa.invoke(<generated>)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastMethod.invoke(FastMethod.java:53)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleMethodInjector$1.invoke(SingleMethodInjector.java:57)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleMethodInjector.inject(SingleMethodInjector.java:91)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:132)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl$1.call(MembersInjectorImpl.java:93)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl$1.call(MembersInjectorImpl.java:80)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectAndNotify(MembersInjectorImpl.java:80)
    at com.google.inject.internal.Initializer$InjectableReference.get(Initializer.java:174)
    at com.google.inject.internal.Initializer.injectAll(Initializer.java:108)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.injectDynamically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:174)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:110)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:73)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceBuilder.injector(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:126)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.build(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:93)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationLoader.load(GuiceApplicationLoader.scala:21)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(DevServerStart.scala:153)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(DevServerStart.scala:150)
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:150)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:121)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:121)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:119)
    at scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:230)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:119)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:111)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1402)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: Configuration error: Configuration error[Exception during pool initialization]
    at play.api.Configuration$.configError(Configuration.scala:178)
    at play.api.PlayConfig.reportError(Configuration.scala:1048)
    at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool.create(HikariCPModule.scala:69)
    at play.api.db.PooledDatabase.createDataSource(Databases.scala:199)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.dataSource$lzycompute(Databases.scala:124)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.dataSource(Databases.scala:122)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.getConnection(Databases.scala:143)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.getConnection(Databases.scala:139)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi$$anonfun$connect$1.apply(DefaultDBApi.scala:44)
    ... 67 more
```

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Any error messages or stacktrace?

Comment: I get "Cannot connect to database [default]" message when I run the application. I added stacktrace on the bottom of my question.

Comment: You can try connecting to postgres using the command line tool: `psql -h localhost table4you postgres`

Comment: also, you can try specifying `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` for the hostname

Comment: `psql -h localhost table4you postgres ` produces this output: `psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?` Im confused now
When I installed postgresql I set 6789 to be default port. Now I will reinstall postgres and use 5432 as default port. I'll keep in touch

Comment: Oh sorry- I didn't notice you are using a non-standard port. In that case the command to test it is `psql -p 6789 -h localhost table4you postgres`

Comment: Now my port is 5432, and when I enter the above command I get this output in command line:
`psql (9.5.0)
WARNING: Console code page (852) differs from Windows code page (1250)
         8-bit characters might not work correctly. See psql reference
         page "Notes for Windows users" for details.
Type "help" for help.

table4you=#`

Comment: Good- you're successfully connecting using the command line. Now is your play app connecting to the db?

Comment: Its fixed now, I will write the answer. Thank you @robinj :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fixed now, and it works. The problem was I used the old postgresql dependency (made in 2011.) and as soon as I replaced it with new dependency (December 2015.) error just dissapeared.
Thanks @robinj for helping..